# Understanding the final twist in Flying Swords of Dragon Gate

Tags: plot-explanation, flying-swords-of-dragon-gate

Since this is a question about a spoiler, I'm hoping I don't actually have to use spoiler markup.

Near the end of the movie [*Flying Swords of Dragon Gate*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1686784/) one extra twist is thrown into the mix. The "maid" who is said to be bearing the child of Yu Huatian (the head of the West Bureau) betrays the main characters and hopes to assist Yu Huatian.

The way it's presented makes it seem that this was the plan all along. But the beginning of the movie begs to differ. For instance, why would she have stayed with Ling after her life was saved? Was it because they expected Zhao to have saved her, instead of Ling? Then the "maid" decided that she would probably run into Zhao again if she stayed with Ling, even though there didn't seem to be any evidence that this would be the case?

It comes down to two possible scenarios:

1. She is not a maid, was never a maid, likely not pregnant, and just set up as a trap?
2. She is actually a maid, and just keeps falling for Yu Huatian, which is the only reason she decides to help him.

Neither scenarios seem very likely actually. What am I missing?

Comment: @all Unfortunately `flying-swords-of-dragon-gate` is too long for a tag name so I decided to create the more general `dragon-gate` tag (since there seem to be more movies related to this one). Another option might be `flying-swords-dragon-gate` (wihtout the *"of"*), which would fit the neccessary 25 characters, but that seems a bit less readable. I leave this open for others to decide, though I don't see the neccessity for opening a meta-discussion on this right now.

Comment: @ChristianRau I don't see this tag being used more than once regardless.

Comment: @ChristianRau `dragon-gate` tag is fine but it should have a tag summary to explain it that its for `flying-swords-of-dragon-gate`.

Answer (score 1):

The maid was a bit confused about which side she should choose, thus in the end she acts like she's not pregnant and fights whoever she encounters in the dragon temple. She actually loses her mind because there is no hope for them, she thought they would not survive the sand storm.

Answer (score 0):

As it was written 3 years ago, my comment is intended for people looking for an explanation to the ending and bumping into this comment.

- first, no maid had no child with Yu since he is an eunuch
  The Emperor's concubine killed all maid who may carry a child of him.
- Secondly, the maid explains she is an agent, so Yu is her boss. She is skillful and know how to fight.

Apart from that, she was probably affected by her saver Zhou Xun and clearly regretted that he came back to save the ML.